# typescript async-await causing variable to be undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

I have this issue I am facing for a while where `vm_res` is is undefined in 
async update_vm_raw_device function, the function `update_vm_raw_device` runs however  the value is udpated like as `/mnt/tank/ds/test_file_test_VM_undefined` please notice undefined in the end.

```
async customSubmit(value) {
  const path = value.raw_file_directory+ '/' + value.raw_filename+ '_'+ value.name;
    const payload = {}
    const vm_payload = {}
    ......SNIP..........
    this.ws.call('vm.get_sharefs').subscribe((get_sharefs)=>{
      if(!get_sharefs){
        this.ws.call('vm.activate_sharefs').subscribe((sharefs)=>{
          this.ws.call('vm.create', [vm_payload]).toPromise().then(vm_res => {
            // here the assignment happens, but  this.vm_res is undefined in 
            // async update_vm_raw_device function.
            this.vm_res = vm_res;
          });
        }
      )
      }
      else {
        this.ws.call('vm.create', [vm_payload]).toPromise().then(vm_res => {
          this.vm_res = vm_res;
        });
      }
    },)
    await this.update_vm_raw_device(vm_payload, this.vm_res);
  }

  async update_vm_raw_device(vm_payload: any, vm_res: number) {
  vm_payload.path = vm_payload.path+"_"+this.vm_res
   await this.ws.call('datastore.update'[vm_payload])]).toPromise().then(
       res=>{});}
```

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` has nothing to do with it.

As far as I can see, `this.vm_res` is only ever getting set inside of a `subscribe` callback, which isn't going to happen before you call `this.update_vm_raw_device()`.

Did you intend to put the call to `this.update_vm_raw_device()` inside of the subscribe handler? Perhaps after setting that value?